# GRUB does not show selection of OS

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub, grub2-mkconfig

I have installed Arch Linux and GRUB afresh. It seems to have worked alright, but when I now boot from the harddisk, I only get the GRUB prompt, without any operating systems to boot. My guess is that the config file does not get loaded somehow, although it does exist.

These are the steps I've done to install the operating system:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/home

arch-chroot /mnt
pacman -S grub efibootmgr
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=arch_grub --recheck --debug
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

How can I start the operating system from grub? Why is it not recognized when making the config?

Comment: Is there any entry for `/` (root filesystem) in `/etc/fstab`? Do all partitions have correct file system type?

Comment: @Biswapriyo There are entries for `/` and for `/home` in `/etc/fstab`. File system type is ext4, except for the efi partition, which is fat.